# How can ı convert RxSwift to Combine Framework

Tags: swift, rx-swift, combine

i want to convert this function to write in Combine framework. I tried a couple way but it didnt work . Can anyone have an idea about this ?

```
func requestAuth(serviceParams: AuthServiceParams) -> Observable<AuthResponse> {
    
    return Observable.create{observer -> Disposable in
        // buradaki işlemler rx 'te yapılacak.
        
        AlamofireService.auth(serviceParams: serviceParams).responseObject {
            (response:DataResponse<AuthResponse>) in
            if(response.error != nil ){
                print("❌⭕️❌ Auth login hatalı bir dönüş aldı sorun var.")
                observer.onError(response.error!)
                observer.onCompleted()
                return
            } else {
                if let data = response.result.value {
                    guard let token = data.data?.token else {
                        print("TOKEN BULUNAMADI")
                        let authResponse = AuthResponse(
                            result: "fault",
                            success: false,
                            data: nil,
                            message: "Kullanıcı adı veya şifre hatalı",
                            errCode: "E0000"
                        )
                        observer.onNext(authResponse)
                        return
                    }
                    print("AuthLogin Token ------->   \(token)")
                    ApplicationVariables.token = token
                    ApplicationVariables.customer = data.data?.customer
                    ApplicationVariables.config = data.data?.store?.config
                    ApplicationVariables.logo = data.data?.store?.logo
                    observer.onNext(data)
                }else {
                    let error = NSError(domain: "Bir sorun oluştu. Lütfen yöneticinize başvurunuz.", code: 1001, userInfo: nil)
                    observer.onError(error)
                }
                observer.onCompleted()
            }
        }
        return Disposables.create()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get is to use a `Future` but keep in mind that futures are eager. If you want the function to still be lazy, you will have to wrap it in a `defer` call.

I also cleaned up the code to read in a more linear fashion.

```
func requestAuth(serviceParams: AuthServiceParams) -> Future<AuthResponse, Error> {
    Future { promise in
        AlamofireService.auth(serviceParams: serviceParams).responseObject { response in
            guard response.error == nil else {
                print("❌⭕️❌ Auth login hatalı bir dönüş aldı sorun var.")
                promise(.failure(response.error!))
                return
            }
            guard let data = response.result.value else {
                let error = NSError(domain: "Bir sorun oluştu. Lütfen yöneticinize başvurunuz.", code: 1001, userInfo: nil)
                promise(.failure(error))
                return
            }
            guard let token = data.data?.token else {
                print("TOKEN BULUNAMADI")
                let authResponse = AuthResponse(
                    result: "fault",
                    success: false,
                    data: nil,
                    message: "Kullanıcı adı veya şifre hatalı",
                    errCode: "E0000"
                )
                promise(.success(authResponse))
                return
            }
            print("AuthLogin Token ------->   \(token)")
            ApplicationVariables.token = token
            ApplicationVariables.customer = data.data?.customer
            ApplicationVariables.config = data.data?.store?.config
            ApplicationVariables.logo = data.data?.store?.logo
            promise(.success(data))
        }
    }
}
```